# Save file on a solid POD

Tags: javascript, rest, solid

What is the preferred method to save a file, be it `turtle` or an image or a video etc. on a solid POD?

The documentation at https://linkeddata.github.io/rdflib.js/doc/Fetcher.html is, as stated in the readme, of limited usefulness in its current state.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use solid-file-client for that

https://github.com/jeff-zucker/solid-file-client

Answer (score 3):

To add to the accepted answer, `@inrupt/solid-client` also has support for storing plain files on a Pod: https://docs.inrupt.com/developer-tools/javascript/client-libraries/tutorial/read-write-files/

(Although if you plan on writing [Turtle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Turtle_(syntax)), it's probably best to use [its specialised API](https://docs.inrupt.com/developer-tools/javascript/client-libraries/tutorial/read-write-data/).)